# how to append div to left of parent in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this code in controller:

```
demo.$inject = ['$scope'];

  demo.directive("boxCreator", function($compile){
      return{
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope , element){
              element.bind("click", function(e) {

                  var childNode = $compile('<div ng-drop="true"> <span class="title">Drop area #2</span> <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects2" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj" ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess2($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}"> {{obj.name}}</div></div>')(scope)
                  element.parent().append(childNode);
              });
          }
      }
  });
```

and i want to append on left side of click. how i can do this?

Comment: what do you mean with "append on left side"?

Comment: @ddb append on left of parent element

Answer (score 2):

I have try this and it will work for me

```
element.parent().prepend(childNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
childNode.insertBefore(element.parent());
```

this way `childNode` will be inserted before (or *at left* if you like) of `element`'s `parent` node, as per [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)